# A bound on the codimension of a ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Assume $R$ is a local ring and that $R=S/I$ with $S$ regular. How can I prove that the minimum number of generators of $I$ is greater or equal to $\dim S-\dim R$ and that equality holds if and only if $R$ is a complete intersection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint.** If $S$ is a Cohen-Macaulay local ring and $I\subset S$ an ideal, what about $\dim S-\dim S/I$?